# Strange behaviour for an uninterned symbol

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

A binary file is generated from a .lisp file that contains the following definitions:

```
 (in-package :xpto)

 (defmacro defparam (name init.value)  
     `(progn  
      (defvar ,name ,init.value)  
      (eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)  
         (export ',name "xpto"))))  

  (defparam myparam 10)

  (defun getparam()
     myparam)
```

So, I want to make a patch file in order to overwrite that symbol, therefore, something like that came to mind:

```
;; Unintern the given symbol because otherwise we are not able to overwrite it
;; once it was set through defvar
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)  
             (unintern 'xpto::myparam :xpto))
```

After loading the patch file, the strange behaviour started to show up:

```
>  :pa xpto
>  myparam  
>> Error: Attempt to take the value of the unbound variable `myparam'
```

The above output is what I was expecting but this one is bothering me:

```
>  (getparam)
>> 10
```

I was expecting that no value was returned because the symbol no longer exists.
How can I remove/unintern **myparam** symbol in a way that any reference to it return the error message shown above ?

p.s: Running the following expression in the patch file is not a valid option for me:

```
(setf myparam 20)
```

Comment: This isn't a question. Please add more detail so people can help. What is this for? What did your expect? What happened instead?

Comment: Hi, I have changed the question in order to fullfill my needs. TY for the feedback.

Comment: Note that you export from a package named "xpto", not "XPTO". The symbol :XPTO has also an uppercase name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you evaluated `(defun getparam)`, it remembered the symbol `myparam` and whenever you call `(getparam)`, it returns the symbols value. The uninterning of `myparam` means that you cannot find the symbol in the package by name, but the symbol object still exists.

```
(defvar myparam 10)
(defun getparam() myparam)
#'getparam
==> #<FUNCTION GETPARAM NIL ... (BLOCK GETPARAM MYPARAM)>
(unintern 'myparam)
#'getparam
==> #<FUNCTION GETPARAM NIL ... (BLOCK GETPARAM #:MYPARAM)>
(getparam)
==> 10
```

note that the second printout of the function contains an uninterned symbol.

### EDIT

> How can I remove/unintern myparam symbol in a way that any reference to it return the error message shown above ?

There is no way - except for redefining `getparam`.

However, you can define `getparam` differently:

```
(defvar myparam 10)
(defun getparam() 
  (symbol-value (or (find-symbol "MYPARAM") 
                    (error "Symbol MYPARAM does not exist"))))
(getparam)
==> 10
(unintern 'myparam)
(getparam)
*** - Symbol MYPARAM does not exist
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also make a symbol unbound:

```
CL-USER 4 > (defvar foosym 10)
FOOSYM

CL-USER 5 > foosym
10

CL-USER 6 > (makunbound 'foosym)
FOOSYM

CL-USER 7 > foosym

Error: The variable FOOSYM is unbound.
```

Comment: Which is the difference between unintern versus unbound a symbol ?

Comment: @utxeee Unintern means to remove a symbol object from a package, so that the symbol can no longer be found in the package using that symbol's name as a key. Doing so does not destroy the symbol, which, like any other object, continues to exist while referenced.  `mkunbound` operates on a variable which is named by the symbol:  it deletes the value cell associated with the variable in the current dynamic environment, if there is such a variable and if it has a value cell. The variable is not destroyed; a value can be restored by assigning a new one to it.

Comment: `makunbound` can have a purely local effect! For instance if we `(defparameter a 42)` at the top level and then evaluate this: `(let ((a 43)) (makunbound 'a))` what is removed is the `let` form's local rebinding of `a`. When the form terminates, the prior binding of `a` containing 42 is revealed.  The `let` temporarily binds the symbol to a new variable location, and that location has its own value which can be deleted by `makunbound` and restored by an assignment, without influencing the original toplevel one.